# What is the difference between get+gerund ot get+v3

Tags: grammar

V3(3rd form of verb)

Btw what is the difference between

Get+gerund

Or get+v3

Comment: Include examples please.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused. I don't know what the 3rd form of the verb is or v3. Please explain.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola It's another name for the past participle.  They're asking about *get V-ing* versus *get V-ed*.

Comment: Idiomatically, *get + gerund* is a pretty unusual combination. I can contrive, for example, *When doing the Christmas food shopping, don't forget to **get stuffing** for the turkey*. To which, of course, the response might be ***Get stuffed!** - I'm a vegetarian!* There are other contexts though, such as the imperatives ***Get moving!*** and ***Get lost!***

Comment: I think in "get stuffing for the turkey", "stuffing" is a noun; not a gerund.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about Passive Causative.

There are 3 types of it:

**To have/get something done** - means that something will be done by someone as a service.
Ex. **I will have my hair cut.**

**To have someone do/To get someone to do** - means you will have something doing something for you. Ex. **I will have Joe repair my car**

**To have/get something V+ing** - is mostly used for things like starting your car. Ex. **Get your car running**

Answer (score 1):

*Get X-ing* means to start X-ing.  It implies urgency that a normal imperative mood doesn't have.  For extra urgency you can say *Go get X-ing*.

> Cook when you feel like it.
>
> Get cooking, they will be here soon.
>
> Go get cooking, they are already here.

*Get X-ed* generally means to do what is needed to transition in a state where you are X-ed.

> I got my hair cut = I went to the barbershop, sat in a chair, waited while he cut my hair, paid them, and left the barbershop.
>
> I got my car registered at the DMV = I went to the DMV, waited in line for 2 hours, performed the registration procedure for my car.

It can also mean "to become X-ed"

> My forearm got swollen after the accident.
>
> I got drunk last night.
>
> I got left behind.